# Zend - How to install on WAMP

Tags: zend-framework

If there is an easy to follow instruction or tutorial that I can use to learn how to install Zend on my machine that has a WAMP installation?

The video listed
http://www.zendcasts.com/getting-started-with-zend-and-wamp-server/2009/06/

is hard to read what he is writing.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually, the whole thing is:

1. Create virtual host pointing it to the sample app
2. Make sure that PHP `include_path` contains the path to the Zend library.

But the specifics can be tricky if you are not accustomed to it. So here is at least a little bit more color.

1. Create a folder for your app, something like `C:\apps\myapp`.
2. Copy a sample ZF app - like [this](http://framework.zend.com/demos/ZendFrameworkQuickstart.zip) or [this](http://github.com/harikt/zfbase) - into that space so that the `myapp` folder has the typical subfolders like `application`, `library`, `public`, `tests`, etc.
3. create a virtual host within your Apache. This is a two step process:

   3.1 Modify your `hosts` file - on my WinXP machine, it resides in the folder `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc` to contain a line like

   `127.0.0.1 myvirtualapp`

   I am intentionally choosing a virtual host name `myvirtualapp` that is different from the app folder name `myapp` to demonstrate that they are conceptually different creatures. One is a name that the OS and Apache recognize as an HTTP host; the other is a local filesystem path.

   3.2 Add an entry into Apache's vhost file - typically in the Apache folder hierarchy at something like `conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`. A minimal entry there will look something like this:

   <VirtualHost *:80>

   DocumentRoot "C:/apps/myapp/public"

   ServerName myvirtualapp

   </VirtualHost>
4. Restart Apache.
5. Make sure that the Zend library is copied into your `c:\apps\myapp\library` folder, so that there is a subfolder named `Zend` with the rest of the library contained inside.
6. Make sure that the folder `c:\apps\myapp\library` is on your PHP include path. There are many ways to do this, but typically this is done in `c:\apps\myapp\public\index.php`. Usually, that `library` folder is referenced in `index.php` as `realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library')`.
7. Browse to the url: `http://myvirtualapp/`

With any luck, you should see the app!

Comment: Hello DavidW,

Thank you so much for your great helps.

Answer (score 0):

Even though [Zend Core](http://www.zend.com/en/products/core/) is being phased out, it might be easier for you to use this instead of WAMP. Zend Core is similar to WAMP, but includes the framework too.

The [Zend Server Community Edition](http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/index), which is what is replacing Zend Core might also suit your purposes.

Comment: Hello Marcus,

I have read the short introduction for Zend Server Community Edition on http://www.zend.com/en/products/server-ce/index.

Basically, I can replace it for WAMP that I am using now.

One more question for you, when I upload my application into the web hosting company, what should I do to make it work there?

Should I request them to install the Zend Server or I just upload the Zend Library.

I feel a little confused here.

Thank you

Comment: @q0987 other then uploading the library yourself and pointing index.php to them you should not have anything to do if everything was setup correctly on both sides. You do not need zend sevrer at all on your web hosting account.