# Problems while Developing MVC Projects using WAMP server

Tags: php, apache, zend-framework, wamp

I am trying to develop websites using Zend Framework. But I came to a strange problem, the public folder is not showing up. I was suppose to change the apache's configuration to redirect http://localhost/ to http://localhost/public, but there are many projects inside the WWW folder, which has to be accesed.

I can enable the mod_rewrite to bring out the public folder, but I am not allowed to change it while I upload it to the actual web server. Is there anyway to solve this problem?

May be a .htaccess file to change the site root folder would be of help.

Comment: I have also posted this question on ServerFault.com, but I found two question here on stackoverflow, related to this problem, So I thought It would be better If you upload this question here also.

Comment: in the zend tutorial `Since the public directory will contain all files that should be directly accessible via our web server, you must set your web server's document root to this directory. Please check your web server's documentation on how to do this.` is said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379025/zend-how-to-install-on-wamp/3387154#3387154) is a detailed description of manually setting up your virtual host and configuring a basic ZF app to run. Hopefully it will help.

**Update:** Given your edited question, perhaps my [blog post](http://www.papayasoft.com/2010/05/08/zend-framework-shared-hosting/) discussing one approach to deploying a ZF app on shared hosting might be helpful.

Comment: Check my comment also, may be that would give you an idea

Comment: Right, one thing about shared hosting is that you usually can't create a virtual host that points to the `public` folder, like the standard ZF setup suggests. The blog post referenced in my answer presents a pretty painless way to remove the `public` folder and have its contents reside at the web root of your shared hosting.