# Setting Up Zend in Wamp server

Tags: zend-framework, configuration, setup-project, wampserver

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Zend - How to install on WAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379025/zend-how-to-install-on-wamp)

I have a website created in Zend Framework.
But when iam trying to load in wamp server it is not working correctly.

If there is any set up steps in wamp for zend?

How can setup zend frame work website in wamp server?

In this site there have a login page , when i login correctly it will displays a white page only nothing will be loaded.

What is the reason?the login page is displayed correctly but after login the site is not loaded

Comment: see [http://stackoverflow.com/q/3379025/1145086]

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that the rewrite_module is enabled Go to Wamp Server -> Apache -> Apache Modules
2. Deploy your project to a folder in your document root folder, default www for example projectname
3. You need to change the .htaccess in the public folder of your Zend Application as follows

   RewriteEngine On

   # the base for rewriting the files, this is relative to the document root being used
    # for local environment use the name of the project folder

   RewriteBase /projectname/public/

   # Rewrite conditions for the Front controller

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

   RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

   RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
4. Access your project as http://localhost/projectname/public

Comment: Or set up a vhost and access your project as http://project.localhost

Comment: I have always found virtualhosts to be a pain since you need to change the configuration files, when using this option, all you need to do is deploy your project and you are good to go

Comment: I used to find that too, but now I wouldn't do it any other way as  I have tailored my set up to make it work much better than the alternative.