# Access to folders under localhost/htdocs some work and some do not

Tags: apache, mysql

I have apache2.2 installed on my Win7 laptop along with php5.3.  I can run html and php files with no problems in the htdocs folder and also under a folder called htdocs/myzftest/public/index.php.

I just installed MySQL and it seems to work ok.  I then downloaded phpMyAdmin to htdocs/phpMyAdmin and tried to run index.php from there but I get The requested URL /phpMyAdmin/index.php was not found on this server.

Why can I access an index.php under one subfolder but not another?

I saw some posts about .htaccess files but I dont know how/where to use it.

Thanks
Dan

Comment: Doublecheck: is there an index.php in htdocs/phpmyadmin/ ?

Comment: Yes.  I tried adding a folder called htdocs/newfolder and place an index.php file there having only an echo.  This works.  I took that same basic file and placed it in htdocs/phpMyAdmin and I get file not found.

Comment: Does the phpmyadmin folder include a htaccess file?

Comment: no.  nor does my htdocs/newfolder have one.

Comment: Try backing up the existing index.php from phpmyadmin, create a new just with echo something and test that. Also check if you are spelling the url to phpmyadmin correct (upper/lower-case etc.)

Comment: Look in apache error logs. Maybe there's a clue there

Comment: Did that too.  I placed my index.php file containing only an echo statement into htdocs/phpMyAdmin  In the url I type localhost/phpMyAdmin/index.php and still get file not found.  Its like apache is not finding files in this subfolder but it does work for other subfolders.  Here is the physical location on my drive C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\phpMyAdmin

Comment: What does the apache error log say?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2012:08:08:34 -0400] "GET /newfolder/index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 10
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Apr/2012:08:09:07 -0400] "GET /phpMyAdmin/index.php HTTP/1.1" 404 218

Comment: That's from the access.log (isn't it?). Look in the error.log

Comment: [Fri Apr 06 08:09:07 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/Program Files/Zend/phpMyAdmin

Comment: Trial and error...I renamed phpMyAdmin to phpmyadmin and it works fine now.  Well thats good news but why does mixed case not work?

Comment: Good you got it working ;) Dunno about the mixed case thing

Answer (score 0):

1. I would like to first suggest that you replace your custom Apache + PHP 5.3 + MySQL installation with a WAMP (www.wampserver.com/en/) which is already integrated and configured.
2. It also comes with prebuilt phpMyAdmin so you will not need to download or configure that too.
3. I am assuming that you will be using Zend Framework for your projects seeing zftest, you can follow the steps here [Setting Up Zend in Wamp server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616903/setting-up-zend-in-wamp-server/9617284#9617284)

Comment: In my experience, WAMP is a big mess. And if he already has the server up and running there should be no need to reinstall it all a new way

Comment: access to all other subfolders seems to work.  Its just this one.

Comment: @mowgli its just a suggestion 

99Valk since you want database access then try Adminer (http://www.adminer.org/) a single file MySQL database management tool, which I have found a suitable replacement for the complexity of PHPMyAdmin. Just unzip the file and drop it at the root of htdocs

Comment: This does not answer my question...why cant I access even a simple php file under phpMyAdmin

Comment: What is the name of the phpmyadmin folder (I know Windows is not case sensitive)? Do you have any .htaccess files within the htdocs folder? If so what are the contents of those files?

Comment: i can add a new folder under htdocs and put my simple index.php there and it works fine

Comment: How are u accessing your urls, http://localhost or http://127.0.0.1? Is your MySQL database running? Did you change the default MySQL password for root?

Comment: Trial and error...I renamed phpMyAdmin to phpmyadmin and it works fine now. Well thats good news but why does mixed case not work?

Comment: mixed case is tricky since Apache, PHP and most systems were ported from *NIX which is case sensitive. My development policy is that everything is lower case unless it has to be a different case, so that's how I avoid most issues. Well at least that is solved

Comment: I do the same. Always use lowercase in foldernames at least ;)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you have an alias for phpadmin in one of your conf files suach as in httpd.conf.
I for example, have this in httpd-xampp.conf:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/Program Files/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/Program Files/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>
```

This redirects calls to phpMyAdmin to the directory `C:/Program Files/xampp/phpMyAdmin` instead of `C:/Program Files/xampp/htdocs/phpMyAdmin`